# Laravel blade Массивы

Tags: php, laravel, blade

У меня есть такие данные [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот эти данных как я могу распечатать на laravel blade
точнее из массива photos
можете помощь пожалуйста

Comment: `$array['cck_params']['photos']`?

Comment: Так пробовал но он выдает ошибку illegal string offset 'photos'

Comment: `$array['cck_params']['photos'][0]`?

Comment: нет я ошибся если я использую так $item['cck_params']['photos'] тогда получаю вот такую ошибку htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: а если делаю так $array['cck_params']['photos'][0] то вот такую ошибку выдает Undefined offset: 0

Comment: Воткни в цикл. Старайся все данные вытаскивать через цикл.

Comment: А как, не подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: я это через foreach прогоняю